# Tag merge request: [feed], [feeds], [syndication-feed], [syndicationfeed]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, retag-request

[feed](/questions/tagged/feed) **× 227**

[feeds](/questions/tagged/feeds) **× 301**

[syndication-feed](/questions/tagged/syndication-feed) **× 24**

[syndicationfeed](/questions/tagged/syndicationfeed) **× 8**