# Tag merge request: [amd64] [x86-64]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

[amd64](/questions/tagged/amd64) **× 23**

[x86-64](/questions/tagged/x86-64) **× 196**

The questions do seem to be generally about the architecture, not about AMD processors specifically.

Comment: Can't one just be proposed as synonym of other?

Comment: I copied the format of this question from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86382/tag-merge-request-feed-feeds-syndication-feed-syndicationfeed, I'm not sure what the difference is; I thought that _was_ what I was proposing.

Comment: I mean here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86-64/synonyms You can access it by following the *synonyms* link on the tag main page.

Comment: I suggest adding x64 to this merge request.